# C++ code to overload the assignment operator does not work

Tags: c++

I'm having some issues compiling the code I wrote which has a custom class with an overloaded `=`.

rnumber.hpp:

```cpp
#include <string>

class rnumber {
public:
  std::string number;

  // I added this constructor in an edit
  rnumber(std::string s) { number = s; }

  void operator=(std::string s) { number = s; }
  bool operator==(std::string s) { return number == s; }
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const rnumber n);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const rnumber n) {
  os << n.number;
  return os;
}
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "rnumber.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  rnumber a = "123";
}
```

For some reason, this does not compile with the error `conversion from ‘const char [4]’ to non-scalar type ‘rnumber’ requested`. This shouldn't be a problem, because `rnumber` has an overload for `=`. Why am I getting this error?

EDIT: Even after adding a constructor, it doesn't work.

Comment: `rnumber a = "123";` isn't an assignment, it is an initialisation

Comment: @Caleth is there a way to overload the 'initialisation' operator?

Comment: _"EDIT: Even after adding a constructor, it doesn't work."_ Works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/jK97srvrx

Comment: Initialisation of class types is done by a constructor. Which constructor is picked by overload resolution.

Comment: @jabaa that's not the same constructor

Comment: @avighnac *"s there a way to overload the 'initialisation' operator?... "* You don't need to. Just use `rnumber a("123");`.

Comment: @Caleth OP edited in the constructor afterwards

Comment: You have to implement the correct constructor. `"123"` is a C-string literal, not a string. `"123"s` is a string literal.

Comment: unrelated, that ctor really should be `rnumber(std::string s) noexcept  : number(std::move(s)) {}`

Comment: @Jabberwocky but there's only one constructor in the entire thing: the one I added when I edited the post. I've also added a comment next to it.

Comment: @avighnac OK forget my comment, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rnumber a = "123";` tries to initialize `a` with a `const char*`, but there is no constructor taking a `const char*`.

You need to implement this constructor as well:

```
  rnumber(const char *s) { number = s; }
```

There are other possibilities, mentioned on other answer and comments.

Comment: Inside a constructor you should initialise members, not assign to them.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that `rnumber a = "123";` is **initialization** and not **assignment** so that the copy assignment `operator=` cannot be used.

There are 2 ways to solve this as shown below:

##### Method 1

Use the converting constructor `rnumber::rnumber(std::string)`

```
int main() {
  rnumber a("123"); //this uses the converting ctor
  
}
```

---

##### Method 2

Create the object and then do the assignment:

```
int main() {
  rnumber a("somestring"); //creates the object using converting ctor 
  a = "123";               //uses assignment operator 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"abc" is not a `std::string` literal, it is a string literal, in particular it is a `const char[4]`. There is an implicit conversion from `const char[4]` to `std::string`, by one of it's constructors, and an implicit conversion from `std::string` to `rnumber` by the constructor you edited in, but you only get one implicit constructor per initialisation.

What you can do is *explicitly* construct the `rnumber`, and the `std::string` parameter can be implicitly constructed.

```
int main() {
  rnumber a { "123" };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem's that I was using the wrong constructor.

`rnumber(std::string s) { number = s; }` is an `std::string` constructor, where the assignment `rnumber a = "123";` is assigning a `const char*` to `a`.

Add another constructor `rnumber(const char *s) { number = s; }` to the header.